# Monero daemon with --rpc-bind-ip parameter

Tags: monerod

After installation of the new version v0.10.2.1, I have started monerod with the parameter "--rpc-bind-ip 192.168.1.2" and got this error:

"ERROR   default src/rpc/rpc_args.cpp:76 --rpc-bind-ip permits inbound unencrypted external connections. Consider SSH tunnel or SSL proxy instead. Override with --confirm-external-bind"

Could somebody explain this ? Previous version 10.1.0 doesn't show this error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error is due to an abundance of caution in preventing the daemon RPC from being accessible from the outside without the user really understanding the consequences.

Here, if you really intend the RPC to be accessible from other machines, you can just add `--confirm-external-bind` to your command line, as the message says. Adding this option serves as a confirmation from the user that they really underand that (unencrypted) external access will be enabled.

Alternatively, if you know how set up an SSH tunnel, you could do that instead, which would allow listening only on 127.0.0.1, while allowing tunneled access to the external machine you want to use it from, with the advantage of encryption and authentication (and I don't know how to do that offhand, but looking for ssh tunnel on duckduckgo should give good pointers).

Comment: Do you know of any efforts to provide authentication & encryption without relying on external tools?  I suppose Kovri will eventually work, but may be years away.